# scrollmagic Section Wipes - end of effect

Tags: html, css, scrollmagic

im trying to add some sections after pinned sections but the pined panels don't go away after end of effect and other sections always go under the wiping sections 
here is my code

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://scrollmagic.io/css/examples.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://scrollmagic.io/css/style.css" type="text/css">
<script src="http://scrollmagic.io/js/lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://scrollmagic.io/js/lib/greensock/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://scrollmagic.io/scrollmagic/uncompressed/ScrollMagic.js"></script>
<script src="http://scrollmagic.io/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/animation.gsap.js"></script>
<script src="http://scrollmagic.io/scrollmagic/uncompressed/plugins/debug.addIndicators.js"></script>

<body>
 <div id="content-wrapper">
  <div id="example-wrapper">
   <div class="scrollContent">
    <section id="titlechart">
     <div id="description">
      <h1 class="badge gsap">Section Wipes (manual)</h1>
      
     </div>
    </section>
    <section class="demo" id="section-wipes">
     <style type="text/css">
      #pinContainer {
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%;
       overflow: hidden;
      }
      .panel {
       height: 100%;
       width: 100%;
       position: absolute;
      }
     </style>
     <div id="pinContainer">
      <section class="panel blue">
       <b>ONE</b>
      </section>
      <section class="panel turqoise">
       <b>TWO</b>
      </section>
      <section class="panel green">
       <b>THREE</b>
      </section>
      <section class="panel bordeaux">
       <b>FOUR</b>
      </section>
     </div>
     <script>
      $(function () { // wait for document ready
       // init
       var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

       // define movement of panels
       var wipeAnimation = new TimelineMax()
        .fromTo("section.panel.turqoise", 1, {x: "-100%"}, {x: "0%", ease: Linear.easeNone})  // in from left
        .fromTo("section.panel.green",    1, {x:  "100%"}, {x: "0%", ease: Linear.easeNone})  // in from right
        .fromTo("section.panel.bordeaux", 1, {y: "-100%"}, {y: "0%", ease: Linear.easeNone}); // in from top

       // create scene to pin and link animation
       new ScrollMagic.Scene({
         triggerElement: "#pinContainer",
         triggerHook: "onLeave",
         duration: "300%"
        })
        .setPin("#pinContainer")
        .setTween(wipeAnimation)
        .addIndicators() // add indicators (requires plugin)
        .addTo(controller);
      });
     </script>
    </section>

      </div>
      <section id="aboutus">
        <div id="description1">

        </div>
      </section>

      <section id="contactus">
        <div id="description2">

        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

i tried to change triggerHook and duration but it distorted the page 
i think the problem is with duration 300% and page height is also 100%

---

im just trying to add some sections at the end of this example 
http://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/section_wipes_manual.html
the point is to add wips effect to some sections in my site
tnx

Comment: Converted to snippet, can you get it working?

Comment: it works now.... 
its realy usles if i cant use this effect anywhere on my page